# Ubuntu 15.10 doesn't recognize my USB 3.0 flash drive

Tags: usb, mount, usb-drive

I have a 8 GB USB 3.0 Silicon Power flash memory. I'd been using it on my laptop,which only has three USB 2.0 ports, until it didn't anymore mount on Ubuntu after being plugged in. The problem is that the stick doesn't show up in any output of the system. I've tried `sudo fdisk -l` , `lsusb` with my USB stick being plugged in. I have no idea what the problem with my USB stick is as it works properly on Windows. I don't know what I have to do.

Here is the output of **`dmesg|tail`**:

```
[   23.275637] wlo1: authenticate with 60:e3:27:4f:23:80
[   23.306725] wlo1: send auth to 60:e3:27:4f:23:80 (try 1/3)
[   23.309681] wlo1: authenticated
[   23.309833] wlo1: waiting for beacon from 60:e3:27:4f:23:80
[   23.317179] wlo1: associate with 60:e3:27:4f:23:80 (try 1/3)
[   23.320968] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 60:e3:27:4f:23:80 (capab=0x431 
  status=0 aid=2)
[   23.323954] wlo1: associated
[   23.324021] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlo1: link becomes ready
[  704.749932] perf interrupt took too long (2516 > 2500), lowering
  kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
[ 2753.020391] perf interrupt took too long (5017 > 5000), lowering
  kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 25000
```

And here is the output of **`lsblk`**:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

sda      8:0    0 298.1G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 191.9G  0 part /media/mohammad/5636ECE213F9AD46
├─sda5   8:5    0   3.8G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0 102.4G  0 part /

sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

The output of **`lsusb`**:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 090c:037c Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan
  (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) 300k Pixel Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:0007 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS451
  Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The output of **`usb-devices`**:

```
 T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 3
 D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
 P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.02
 S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.2.0-38-generic ehci_hcd
 S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
 S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1a.0
 C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
 I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

 T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 6
 D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
 P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0020 Rev=00.00
 C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
 I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

 T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=02 Cnt=01 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
 D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=12 Prot=ff MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1
 P:  Vendor=138a ProdID=0007 Rev=00.72
 S:  SerialNumber=00b086f83089
 C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA
 I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 4 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)

 T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=04 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
 D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=ef(misc ) Sub=02 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
 P:  Vendor=090c ProdID=037c Rev=00.05
 S:  Manufacturer=Image Processor
 S:  Product=USB 2.0 PC Cam
 C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA
 I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=0e(video) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo
 I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=0e(video) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=uvcvideo

 T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 3
 D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
 P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=04.02
 S:  Manufacturer=Linux 4.2.0-38-generic ehci_hcd
 S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller
 S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:1d.0
 C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
 I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub

 T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=480 MxCh= 8
 D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=01 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
 P:  Vendor=8087 ProdID=0020 Rev=00.00
 C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA
 I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub
```

The output of **`lspci | grep USB`**:

```
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset
USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset
USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 05)
```

And the output of **`dmesg | grep usb`**:

```
[    0.730867] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.730876] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.730895] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.667842] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.667844] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.667846] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.667848] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.2.0-38-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.667849] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    1.683969] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.683975] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.683979] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.683982] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 4.2.0-38-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.683985] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.980034] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.996088] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using  ehci-pci
[    2.112520] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0020
[    2.112525] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.128829] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0020
[    2.128836] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.384305] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    2.478293] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=138a, idProduct=0007
[    2.478298] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=1
[    2.478302] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 00b086f83089
[    2.548374] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[    2.648332] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=037c
[    2.648338] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.648341] usb 1-1.5: Product: USB 2.0 PC Cam
[    2.648343] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Image Processor
[   11.194010] input: USB 2.0 PC Cam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/input/input22
[   11.194192] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

Comment: Sorry but I think It's `fdisk -l` output.

Comment: The output of dmesg|tail is not shown in the question. You can have a look at it by clicking on the link in the last line of the question. Here is the link:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/wzr6Z.png

Comment: Does anybody have any idea what the problem is???

Comment: Did you try to plug USB 2.0? Does it work ?

Comment: try to insert your usb, open up the terminal and type `sudo modprobe usb-storage`

Comment: Yes, I tried USB 2.0 and even other USB 3.0s, they work properly. If there was something wrong with my USB 3.0, it wouldn't work on Windows but it does. I ran `sudo modprobe usb-storage` and nothing happened!

Comment: Can you try [this](https://hardforum.com/threads/ubuntu-usb3-not-working.1807755/)

Comment: Thanks for your help but the instruction on the page you suggested didn't work too...

Comment: Has this problem been resolved?  I wonder if it has been fixed by a more recent kernel?